# Importing .sql file into postgresql or Mysql from Local Machine

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm trying to import 15GB .sql file in postgreysql or Mysql database. What is the faster way or procedure to import such a big dataset in short time.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated ?

Comment: linux or windows? If linux then just use command line, psql -f file.sql

Comment: @FaddishWorm I'm trying in Mac OS basically unix environment. Can you please give me a example of this command psql -f file.sql ?

Answer (score 3):

To start with, there's really no such thing as a ".sql file". It's like saying a ".dat file", it could be practically anything. A list of `INSERT`s. A script to create tables. A query that extracts information from an existing database. Etc.

The file might contain table and index definitions (DDL) and other content, or it might just be a list of `INSERT` statements. It could be written to use custom vendor extensions like PostgreSQL's `COPY` command for fast data loading, too.

You need to look at the file and see what it is. Determine if you need to create tables to hold the data first. See if you need to change any DDL to be compatible with the target database, since unfortunately the standard names for SQL data types aren't followed all that consistently by database vendors, there are vendor extensions for things like key generation, etc.

If it's plain `INSERT`s into a single table and the inserts don't depend on each other the fastest way to load it into PostgreSQL is to split it into several chunks and run each chunk with `psql -1 -v ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK=1 -f chunk.sql`.

Otherwise you'd just have to `psql -1 -v ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK=1 -f thefile.sql`.

The fastest way to load data into PostgreSQL is to use `pg_bulkload`, but that's quite disruptive and I don't think it'll take pre-formatted SQL input. The next-best option is the `COPY` command, but that also works with CSV/TSV, not with SQL formatted data written as `INSERT`s.

Comment: psql -1 -v ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK=1 -f thefile.sql
In this command how I can specify my local machine. For example thefile.sql is located in my local machine in following location /Users/Foo/Desktop/thefile.sql 
Thanks @Craig Ringer.