# How to import .sql and .xml file from local machine to postgresql using Terminal

Tags: database, postgresql

I want to upload a .sql or .xml file in postgresql database using terminal. I saw several solution as I linked followed, but unfortunately none of them works.

It would be nice to get an example. I'm using psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.5. in Linux environment.
Thanks in advance.
Possible duplicate:
[Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393961/how-to-import-existing-sql-files-in-postgresql-8-4), [Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362381/importing-sql-file-into-postgresql-or-mysql-from-local-machine?noredirect=1#comment25196472_17362381),[Link-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842393/import-sql-dump-into-postgresql-database), [Link-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393961/how-to-import-existing-sql-files-in-postgresql-8-4)

Answer (score -1):

If the .sql file is simply text with with SQL queries in it, then the proper way is:

```
psql -U some_username -d some_database -f name_of_the_file
```

What the .xml file is - I don't know. As far as I know, no native PostgreSQL tools produce XML dumps of database.

If the above wouldn't work, show us part of the file, how you ran it, and what did you get.

Comment: My database structure is as this link: 
http://codepad.org/AtYLV5on
I tried with the command you suggested but it does not even work. FYI, first I connected with the specific database ( command \c database_name) where I want to import all the tables and then I run your command. I dont even get any error message.


Another info, I can run other command like create table or insert in the table using the postgreysql command.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand your comment. \c is command within psql. And I showed how to run psql with file from shell.

Comment: Regarding the name_of_the_file parameter: don't I have to locate the file where it is in my machine. Yes, I run postgreysql command where this file is located. Thanks.

Comment: 1. It's PostgreSQL, not "postgreysql". 2. I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "locate the file".

Comment: So if I run it from the shell how do I specify the host address ?

Comment: What host address? Host of what? Please specify your questions in understandable way. Also - I checked the "structure" link you gave me. It's clearly MySQL creation script, and as such will not work (without some modifications) in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Sry for confusion, what I mean is the path of .sql file for instance /Users/Cris/Desktop/the_file.sql

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32639/discussion-between-depesz-and-user2412714)

Comment: In my server I have PostgreSQL DB and my dump database is located in this location of my machine /Users/Cris/Desktop/the_file.sql
I just want to import this the_file.sql in my server